# Xubuntu installer shows no partitions, crashes

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, xubuntu, system-installation

I'm trying to install Xubuntu 13.04 on an HP Envy h8-1414 desktop computer running Windows 8. I would like to set it up dual-boot. I downloaded the 64-bit AMD desktop ISO onto a USB device and booted from it. I am able to "try ubuntu" just fine - in fact I am writing this message from within Firefox while trying it. But when I try to install it, the installer shows me this when trying to select a partition, see screen shots here: https://sites.google.com/site/masridhar/xubuntu-install-problems (I'd love to show the screen shot inline instead of with a link, but I don't have the 10 reputation points.)
I used gparted to carve out some space for Ubuntu, and it shows me the partition list just fine. I also read in other threads on askubuntu that I should try using gdisk to check for errors in the GPT disk. But that seems to show that everything is fine.

I'd love to get xubuntu going on this machine. Thanks in advance for your help!

Sridhar

Edit: I forgot to mention that when I click the buttons in the partition screen on the installer, it crashes.

Comment: Check out the duplicate question above, Windows 8 is known to cause this problem.